# reselect across multiple comoponents work only with deepEqual check

Tags: performance, reactjs, redux, memoization, reselect

I've tested in various ways... Still, It isn't working.
I don't seem to doing anything wrong

- exactly same code as reselect doc
- redux store is all normalized
- reducers are all immutable

From parent component, I just pass down a prop with id and from child component, connected with redux and used selector to get that exact item by id(from parent component)

```
### This is what Parent components render looks like
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Parent component</h4>
        {this.props.sessionWindow.tabs.map(tabId => 
           <ChildComponentHere key={tabId} tabId={tabId} />  
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

### This is what Child component looks like
render() {
    const { sessionTab } = this.props  (this props is from connect() )
    <div>
        <Tab key={sessionTab.id} tab={sessionTab} />
      </div>
    ))
  }
### Selectors for across multiple components
const getTheTab = (state: any, ownProps: IOwnProps) => state.sessionWindows.sessionTab[ownProps.tabId];
const makeTheTabSelector = () =>
  createSelector(
    [getTheTab],
    (tab: object) => tab
  )
export const makeMapState = () => {
  const theTabSelector = makeTheTabSelector();
  const mapStateToProps = (state: any, props: IOwnProps) => {
    return {
      sessionTab: theTabSelector(state, props)
    }
  }
  return mapStateToProps
}
```

Weirdly Working solution: just change to deep equality check.(from anywhere)

- use selectors with deep equality works as expected.
- at shouldComponentUpdate. use _.isEqual also worked.

.

```
 1. const createDeepEqualSelector = createSelectorCreator(
       defaultMemoize,
       isEqual
    )
 2. if (!_isEqual(this.props, nextProps) || !_isEqual(this.state, nextState)){return true}
```

From my understanding, my redux is always immutable so when something changed It makes new reference(object or array) that's why react re-renders. But when there is 100 items and only 1 item changed, only component with that changed props get to re-render.

To make this happen, I pass down only id(just string. shallow equality(===) works right?)using this id, get exact item.(most of the components get same valued input but few component get different valued input)  Use reselect to memoize the value.  when something updated and each component get new referenced input compare with memoized value and re-render when something trully changed.

This is mostly what I can think of right now... If I have to use _isEqual anyway, why would use reselect??  I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here. can anyone help?

**For more clarification.(hopefully..) 
First,My redux data structure is like this**

```
sessionWindow: {
  byId: {  // window datas byId
    "windowId_111": {
      id: "windowId_111",
      incognito: false,
      tabs: [1,7,3,8,45,468,35,124] // this is for the order of sessionTab datas that this window Item has
    },
    "windowId_222": {
      id: "windowId_222",
        incognito: true,
        tabs: [2, 8, 333, 111]
    },{
      ... keep same data structure as above
    }
  },
  allIds: ["windowId_222", "windowId_111"] // this is for the order of sessionWindow datas
}
sessionTab: {  // I put all tab datas here. each sessionTab doesn't know which sessionWindow they are belong to
  "1": {
    id: 1
    title: "google",
    url: "www.google.com",
    active: false,
    ...more properties
  },
  "7": {
    id: 7
    title: "github",
    url: "www.github.com",
    active: true
  },{
    ...keep same data structure as above
  }
}
```

Problems.
1. when a small portion of data changed, It re-renders all other components.
  Let's say sessionTab with id 7's url and title changed. At my sessionTab Reducer with 'SessionTabUpdated" action dispatched. This is the reducer logic

```
const updateSessionTab = (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    [action.tabId]: {
      ...state[action.tabId],
      title: action.payload.title,
      url: action.payload.url
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing is broken. just using basic reselect doesn't prevent from other components to be re-rendered. I have to use deep equality version to stop re-render the component with no data changed

After few days I've struggled, I started to think that the problem is maybe from my redux data structure? because even if I change one item from sessionTab, It will always make new reference like {...state, [changedTab'id]: {....}}  In the end, I don't know...

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual problem is?  You've described what you've done to try to fix the issue, but not what the issue is in the first place.  What is "broken" when you don't use `_.isEqual` ?  Also, can you post your reducer?

Comment: sorry about late reply, somehow didn't see it from my gmail. I tried to make it clearer. It started from bold subtitle.  short version of edit. 
Problem: component with no data changed still re-renders.
Nothing is broken without _isEqual. Just still component with no data changed still re-renders.

Comment: oh! are you the author of http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/. I've read all your practical and Idiomatic series. It was all great. This structure of redux and react components(not only connect from top containers but many times for performance. pass ids to props. etc...) is by reading your blogs. Probably, I don't fully understand it yet, hahaha

Comment: Haha, thanks, and glad to know those posts have been helpful! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three aspects of your selector definition and usage look a little odd:

- `getTheTab` is digging down through multiple levels at once
- `makeTheTabSelector` has an "output selector" that just returns the value it was given, which means it's the same as `getTheTab`
- In `mapState`, you're passing the entire `props` object to `theTabSelector(state, props)`.

I'd suggest trying this, and see what happens:

```
const selectSessionWindows = state => state.sessionWindows;

const selectSessionTabs = createSelector(
    [selectSessionWindows],
    sessionWindows => sessionWindows.sessionTab
);

const makeTheTabSelector = () => {
    const selectTabById = createSelector(
        [selectSessionTabs, (state, tabId) => tabId],
        (sessionTabs, tabId) => sessionTabs[tabId]
    );
    return selectTabById;
}

export const makeMapState() => {
 const theTabSelector = makeTheTabSelector();
  const mapStateToProps = (state: any, props: IOwnProps) => {
    return {
      sessionTab: theTabSelector(state, props.tabId)
    }
  }
  return mapStateToProps
}
```

No guarantees that will fix things, but it's worth a shot.

You might also want to try using some devtool utilities that will tell you why a component is re-rendering.  I have links to several such tools in the [Devtools#Component Update Monitoring](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/devtools.md#component-update-monitoring) section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links).

Hopefully that will let you figure things out.  Either way, leave a comment and let me know.

Comment: your selector does really make sense, still It re-renders...  when one tab's data changed all the tab components are re-rendered. 
why-did-you-update addon still says "props: Value did not change. Avoidable re-render!"    I removed other HOC in case, still the same result.(I'm using react-dnd)     
  If simply making it deep equal solves re-rendering problem(whether it is from reselect or shouldComponentUpdate), then my data update logic is immutable right? Then using reselect will prevent re-render problem was my guess...  
  Anyway thanks for your big help

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to say what else might be happening without actually having the entire project to look at.

Comment: That's true. I'll keep it this way until my programming skill goes up and can fix this problem.

Comment: I've made the similar example here. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/my3wq7vj) As your advice, passing only ids solves the all problem.(my first attempt to prevent re-render) I don't  seem to need reselect at all...  I don't know what is wrong with my real project...   I'll leave a comment If It is not a stupid mistake and a real problem.

Comment: I think I found it.... It's because of the library I've been using from the beginning... [react-chrome-redux](https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux/issues/10)

Comment: It passes actions between background, contentScript, popup, etc... BUT It returns whole updated state. This is why It re-renders every time. response is always the whole serialized copy of the store.(new object reference) It sounds not familiar if you haven't done chrome extension development.. whew... after I found this, don't know what to do. either build a new library or using current one knowing all this problem...

Comment: or this one [https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux/issues/98](https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux/issues/98)